# Why does multiplication only short circuit on one side

Tags: haskell, short-circuiting

I was messing around with `fix` and after messing around with it I came across some weird behavior, namely that `0 * undefined` is `*** Exception: Prelude.undefined` and `undefined * 0` is `0`. Which also means that `fix (0 *)` is `*** Exception: <<loop>>` and `fix (* 0)` is `0`.

After playing around with it it seems like the reason is because it is non-trivial to make it short circuit in both directions, as that doesn't really make much sense, without some sort of weird parallel computation and start with the first non-bottom returned.

Is this kind of thing seen in other places (reflexive functions that aren't reflexive for bottom values), and is it something I can safely rely on? Also is there a practical way to make both `(0 *)` and `(* 0)` evaluate to zero regardless of the value passed in.

Comment: WHAT? That is awesome!

Comment: This is *exactly* the point that makes [denotational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics) not completely equivalent to [operational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics), i.e. not fully abstract. The former can represent a function `f` with `f undefined 0 = 0` and `f 0 undefined = 0` while the latter cannot. Language implementations follow operational semantics, thus making it impossible to define such an `f` without some trickery.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. There is an [`unamb`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb) package providing tools for the sort of parallel computation you refer to. In fact, it offers `Data.Unamb.pmult`, which tries, in parallel, to check whether each operand is 1 or 0, and if so immediately produces a result. This parallel approach is likely to be much slower in most cases for simple arithmetic!

The short-circuiting of `(*)` occurs *only* in GHC version 7.10. It came about as a result of changes to the implementation of the `Integer` type in that GHC version. That extra laziness was generally seen as a *performance bug* (as it interferes with strictness analysis and can even lead to space leaks in theory), so it will be removed in GHC 8.0.

Comment: Seems like 7.10 [had several surprising "features"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35941674/1139697). :/

Comment: Can you explain the performance bug part. Surely if you KNOW one of the values is 0 it makes no sense from a performance standpoint to evaluate it as well. Can't you just toss it into the abyss at that point?

Comment: @semicolon, GHC uses strictness analysis (specifically, a version it calls demand analysis) to figure out when a value will *always* or *never* be evaluated. Knowing either of these is tremendously useful for optimization. Sometimes (e.g., with `&&`) users expect and rely on short-circuit behavior. In many other situations, the savings in unusual circumstances don't begin to pay for the losses in other ones.

Comment: @dfeuer Ah I see. So if it is always needed it can be executed whenever GHC feels like executing it and also there won't be any unnecessary thunk accumulation?

Comment: @semicolon, something like that, yeah. I don't know too many details, but GHC can use this, for instance, to (effectively) replace `foldl` by `foldl'` in many cases, because it might as well just perform an operation if it knows it will have to eventually. And if it sees that something *never* gets used, it can avoid allocating space for it as well.

Answer (score 7):

Take the following for example

```
(if expensiveTest1 then 0 else 2) * (if expensiveTest2 then 0 else 2)
```

You have to choose a side to evaluate. If `expensiveTest2` is an infinite loop, you will never be able to tell whether the right side is `0` or not, so you can't tell whether or not to short circuit the right side, so you never get to look at the left side. You can't check if both sides are `0` at once.

As for whether you can rely on short circuiting to act in a certain way, just keep in mind that `undefined` and `error` acts *exactly* like an infinite loop as long as you don't use IO. Therefore, you can test short circuiting and laziness using `undefined` and `error`. In general, short circuiting behavior varies from function to function. (There are also different levels of laziness. `undefined` and `Just undefined` may give different results.)

See [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it seems that `fix (* 0) == 0` only works for `Integer`, if you run `fix (* 0) :: Double` or `fix (* 0) :: Int`, you still get `***Exception <<loop>>`

That's because in `instance Num Integer`, `(*)` is defined as `(*) = timesInteger`

`timesInteger` is defined in `Data.Integer`

```
-- | Multiply two 'Integer's
timesInteger :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
timesInteger _       (S# 0#) = S# 0#
timesInteger (S# 0#) _       = S# 0#
timesInteger x       (S# 1#) = x
timesInteger (S# 1#) y       = y
timesInteger x      (S# -1#) = negateInteger x
timesInteger (S# -1#) y      = negateInteger y
timesInteger (S# x#) (S# y#)
  = case mulIntMayOflo# x# y# of
    0# -> S# (x# *# y#)
    _  -> timesInt2Integer x# y#
timesInteger x@(S# _) y      = timesInteger y x
-- no S# as first arg from here on
timesInteger (Jp# x) (Jp# y) = Jp# (timesBigNat x y)
timesInteger (Jp# x) (Jn# y) = Jn# (timesBigNat x y)
timesInteger (Jp# x) (S# y#)
  | isTrue# (y# >=# 0#) = Jp# (timesBigNatWord x (int2Word# y#))
  | True       = Jn# (timesBigNatWord x (int2Word# (negateInt# y#)))
timesInteger (Jn# x) (Jn# y) = Jp# (timesBigNat x y)
timesInteger (Jn# x) (Jp# y) = Jn# (timesBigNat x y)
timesInteger (Jn# x) (S# y#)
  | isTrue# (y# >=# 0#) = Jn# (timesBigNatWord x (int2Word# y#))
  | True       = Jp# (timesBigNatWord x (int2Word# (negateInt# y#)))
```

Look at the above code, if you run `(* 0) x`, then `timesInteger _ (S# 0#)` would match so that `x` would not be evaluated, while if you run `(0 *) x`, then when checking whether `timesInteger _ (S# 0#)` matches, x would be evaluated and cause infinite loop

We can use below code to test it:

```
module Test where
import Data.Function(fix)

-- fix (0 ~*) == 0
-- fix (~* 0) == ***Exception<<loop>>
(~*) :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a -> a
0 ~* _ = 0
_ ~* 0 = 0
x ~* y = x ~* y

-- fix (0 *~) == ***Exception<<loop>>
-- fix (*~ 0) == 0
(*~) :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a -> a
_ *~ 0 = 0
0 *~ _ = 0
x *~ y = x *~ y
```

There is something even more interesting, in GHCI:

```
*Test> let x = fix (* 0) 
*Test> x 
0
*Test> x :: Double 
*** Exception: <<loop>>
*Test>
```

Comment: Eh, that last is just the combo of `NoMonomorphismRestriction` with defaulting. The rest of your answer is great detective work.

Comment: @dfeuer While you are right that it makes perfect sense, I still think it is a pretty interesting. If you were a really bad person you could return any arbitrary `Num a => a` but make it fail when used as anything other than an `Integer`. By just doing `fix (* 0) + retVal`.