# strict or non-strict multiplication in haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc

For a class, I was trying to come up with simple examples of strict and non-strict functions, arguing that non-strict functions make sense. One of my examples was that it might be useful to define 0*x = x*0 = 0 for all x in the domain. When I got back home I naturally wanted to see what the Haskell creators think about that. Here comes my confusion.

At one machine, ghci says that multiplication is strict on both arguments:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> 0 * undefined 
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
Prelude> undefined * 0
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

At another machine, ghci says that multiplication is non-strict on the first argument:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> undefined * 0
0
Prelude> 0 * undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

What causes the difference in behaviour ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but for examples of why laziness is useful you might like [Non-Trivial Lazy Evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868507/non-trivial-lazy-evaluation).

Comment: That is the result of a [bug in GHC 7.10.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049689/why-does-multiplication-only-short-circuit-on-one-side) which didn't exist before 7.10 and was eliminated in 8.1.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Do you know what is the reasoning behind the decision to make multiplication strict?  From my point of view, this is not obvious, because I make a parallel with the fact that True || undefined = True.

Comment: Also, you won't be able to implement a completely lazy `0 * x = x * 0 = 0` in Haskell. One of the sides will need to be evaluated to make sure the first pattern doesn't match (which one depends on which pattern match you put first in your definition).

Comment: I think the reason multiplication is strict is that it would cause a significant performance decrease if it was lazy. If it was lazy in (say) the first argument, something like `((... * x) * y) * z` (with a lot of factors) would need to build up a huge thunk before any actual work (multiplication) can be done.

Comment: It is possible to have a multiplication that is non strict in both arguments using lub (experimental module), see [ptimes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lub-0.1.7/docs/Data-Lub.html)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the comments thanks to @DavidYoung - this is a GHC bug nothing more.

If you want multiplication to be lazy in some particular manner you can certainly write your own type and instance for `Num`.  For example:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main =
  do print (one * two)
     print (undefined * zero)
     putStrLn "The next one has an exception because it must evaluate the undefined arugment."
     print (undefined * two)

one, two, zero :: LazyInt
one = 1
two = 2
zero = 0

-- Not fully lazy such as in addition or Ord, which is possible,
-- but just in the first argument for multiplication.
newtype LazyInt = LI { unLI :: Int }
                deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Show LazyInt where
  show (LI x) = show x

instance Num LazyInt where
  (LI a) + (LI b) = LI (a + b)
  negate (LI a) = LI (negate a)
  abs (LI a) = LI (abs a)
  signum (LI a) = LI (signum a)
  fromInteger i = LI (fromInteger i)

  -- The case of interest:
  a * (LI b) =
    if b == 0
       then LI 0
       else LI (unLI a * b)
```